# Proving $\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

**DISCLAIMER**: This post is not to be confused with [Prove $|x + y|^2 - |x - y|^2 = 2|x|^2 + 2|y|^2$ and interpret its meaning.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502481/prove-x-y2-x-y2-2x2-2y2-and-interpret-its-meaning). This exercise works in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is not necessarily to be interpreted geometrically.

---

**Exercise** Prove that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

*Attempt.* Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+y_i)^2 + \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2$

Now, one thing we know for sure is that

- $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\|+\|y\| \implies (\|x+y\|)^2 \leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2$

But $(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2$ could give us a bunch of middle terms. So in general: $\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 \leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2$

We also have that

- $\|x-y\| = \|x+(-y) \| \leq \|x\|+\|-y\| = \|x\|+\|y\| \implies \|x-y\|^2 \leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2$

which gives the same result as the first bullet.

Am I headed in the right direction here? Is the triangle inequality useful here? What suggestions do you have for my approach and facts so far?

Comment: Triangle inequality is **not** useful here, since it is strict when $x$ and $y$ don't point in the same direction, so you'll never be able to use it for perfectly general equality. If you look at the question you linked to again, you'll notice that a (geometry-free) proof is provided in the question, using dot products.

Comment: @TheoBendit The question I linked has $|x+y|^2- |x-y|^2 = \dots$, which is a difference of two quantities on the LHS. My case is a sum of two quantities, i.e. $\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2 = \dots$

Comment: To expand on the above comment notice that $\langle x+y, x+y\rangle=||x+y||^2$

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange is $\langle x+y, x+y \rangle$ meant to be a dot product?

Comment: @Emily Huh, I missed that. That would be a typo in the original question. The $-$ has to be a $+$ in order for the equality to be true (it will be false whenever $x \neq y$). I've gone ahead and changed it, which I think is warranted, since it caused us some confusion.

Comment: Any inner product really, but yes.  This is called the parallelogram law.

Comment: If you take the other question literally (after correcting the obvious typo in the formula), it says first to prove the statement (your question) and *then* interpret it geometrically. So by the time we're halfway through answering that question we've answered yours. Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: It's a good thing you corrected that title. Thank goodness

Comment: Hmm, on the other hand, looking carefully at the answers to the other question, nobody's really addressing how to do the first half!

Comment: @DavidK I don't think it matters that much. Yes, the dupe target asks a slightly different question, but there is enough of an answer in the body of the linked question, plus the asker seems to have sufficient help here already (as will anyone else who stumbles over this question later).

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah well, one way or another the questions ought to be linked, and now they are.

Comment: @DavidK Technically, they always were. :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=||x+y||^2$ where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By the above remark we should have:
$$\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=||x+y||^2$$
$$\langle x-y,x-y\rangle=||x-y||^2$$

And remember that the inner product is a bilinear form and compute the LHS.
$$\langle x+y,x+y\rangle+ \langle x-y,x-y\rangle$$

It should be your desired equalty as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then

$$\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = (\|x\|^2+2\|x\|\cdot\|y\|+\|y\|^2)  + (\|x\|^2 - 2\|x\| \cdot \|y\| +\|y\|^2)$$

$$= 2\|x\|^2 +2\|x\| \cdot \|y\| - 2\|x\|\cdot \|y\| + 2\|y\|^2$$

$$ = 2\|x\|^2+ 2\|y\|^2 $$

$$= 2(\|x\|^2 +\|y\|^2)$$

Comment: You just about have it. The only thing is that you were a little too generous with the modulus symbols: $x\cdot y$ is not necessarily equal to $\|x\|\cdot\|y\|.$ (Well also you omitted an exponent but that's an obvious typo.)

Comment: @DavidK I apologize, I use ``\cdot`` as a multiplicative operator

Comment: @DavidK Also, I fixed the exponent typo

Comment: It's fine to use the $\cdot$ symbol both for multiplying two magnitudes as well as inner product of two vectors. It was just the wrong place to be multiplying two magnitudes. (Exponent fixed, I see.)